# Finding maximum difference between consecutive elements of an array

Tags: python, list, algorithm

Say I have an array:

```
[44, 30, 24, 32, 35, 30, 40, 38, 15]
```

Here, every number represents a stock value on a certain day. I want to find the maximum profit that could have been made by buying stock on day x and selling stock on day y.

In this case, the function would return `16`, because at index 2 the stock was worth $24 and at index 6 the stock was then worth $40.

Here is my attempt, however I can't figure out how to only look at consecutive elements in the list

```
x = [5, 8, 15, 19]  # total scores
y = [x[i] - x[i-1] if i else x[i] for i in range(len(x))]  # round scores
print(y)
# output
[5, 3, 7, 4]
```

Comment: Why are you focused on consecutive days, since the optimal answer can be across several days?

Comment: Plenty of reference solutions [out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=algorithm+max+stock+profit).

Comment: @dawg, I'd be surprised if this question had not been asked before but it is not the same as the question you cite that serves as the basis for closing. This question is concerned with successive elements, not any pair of elements.

Comment: `max(((t1-e1,(e1,t1)) for i,e1 in enumerate(your_list) for t1 in li[i+1:]))`

Answer (score 1):

Once you pass index `i`, it's never optimal to buy the stock at any value other than `min_{1 <= j <= i} A[j]`, so it's enough to compare the minimum value so far to the present value.

```cpp
int solve(stock_prices) { 
  int answer = 0, min_so_far = stock_prices[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    answer = max(answer, stock_prices[i] - min_so_far);
    min_so_far = min(min_so_far, stock_prices[i]);
  }
  return answer;
}
```

This runs in linear time compared to the other two solutions, both of which are quadratic.

Comment: OP asks for python, which this is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at consecutive elements this way.

```
...
for i in range(len(x):
    for j in range(i+1, len(x)):
...
```

Here is the working one:

```
def max_difference(price_list):
  days = len(price_list)
  max_diff=0
  for i in range(days-1):
    for j in range(i+1, days):
      diff = price_list[j]-price_list[i]
      if(diff > max_diff):
        max_diff=diff
  return max_diff

prices=[10, 30, 40, 32, 35, 30, 40, 38, 15]
print(max_difference(prices))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Ekesh Kumar's answer but converted to Python, and it will also return 0 if there is no positive profit to be made (monotonically decreasing list):

```
#Set initial profit to zero
max_profit = 0
#Grab our first purchase value
min_price_so_far = prices[0]

#Start at 1 so we can compare to the first day price
for i in range(1,len(prices)):
    max_profit = max(max_profit, prices[i] - min_price_so_far)
    min_price_so_far = min(min_price_so_far, prices[i])
    
print(max(max_profit, 0))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).